# Resize font size of UILabel based on Frame in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uilabel

I want to resize the text size of UILabel dynamically. Frame of the UILabel will be changed dynamically. Whenever am changing the UILabel's Frame, font size should be fit with frame.

I have tried below code but there is no effect.

```
label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Finally i found solution.

Here is my calculation

```
    void ResizeLabelFontSize(CGRect frame,UILabel label)
    {
        int fontSize = 3;
        UIFont font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(fontSize);
        CGSize size = label.Text.StringSize(font);
        while (frame.Width > size.Width)
        {
            fontSize++;
            font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(fontSize);
            size = label.Text.StringSize(font);
        }
        label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(fontSize);
    }
```

Comment: You should use auto layout and set the vertical content hugging priority value.  Set that priority value higher than the height constraint, if you have no constraints and don't want to use auto layout, then set the content hugging priority value to 1000 and call the set needs update function on your view after that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` definition [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth?language=objc)

As the documentation said, the size will be **reduced** in roder to fit the label's bounding rectangle, so the font will not get larger dynamically with label's frame, but you can set font very large at the beginning to achieve your requirement, see my test result .

### Code snippet:

```
UILabel label;
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    label = new UILabel(frame: new CGRect(0, 100, 100, 100));
    label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    label.TextColor = UIColor.White;
    label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(1000);
    label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.Clip;
    label.BaselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters;
    label.Text = "label";
    View.AddSubview(label);
}

partial void ButtonIncrease(UIButton sender)
{
    CGRect rect = label.Frame;
    rect.Width = 300;
    rect.Height = 300;
    label.Frame = rect;
}

partial void ButtonDecrease(UIButton sender)
{
    CGRect rect = label.Frame;
    rect.Width = 100;
    rect.Height = 100;
    label.Frame = rect;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you update your code snippet here?

Comment: `label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true ; label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.Clip;label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(100);`

Comment: You are changing the font size manually. But what i want is, i need to calculate the font size based on the frame size

Comment: You don't need to calculate the font size in my solution,it will change dynamically every time with the label frame , you just need to set `label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true ; label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.Clip;label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(100);` at first. In my demonstrate I just create a button click to show this scenario.

Comment: Thanks!. I will try and let you know

Comment: @VenkyDhana I have updated with code snippet . No font size calculation , just use button event to simulate the change of the label frame.